# Can we give privilege on .pem file for ssh connection

Tags: security, ssh, pem

I want to known is it possible to generate .pem file with some restricted privilege. Like a user with .pem can only list the data but not edit it?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what operating system you're using, but it is possible to mark a file as read-only on both Windows and Unix.  That permission is independent of whether the connection is over SSH or not, so if you want to make it impossible for SSH users to edit the file, you must restrict logins over SSH to only those users who do not have write permissions and are not the owner of the file.